# Can't convert to 12 hour clock with php datetime method

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

For some reason I can' make this into 12 hour time format. It comes up as Lead At: 5/26/2018 14:25

```
@if(!empty($user['lead_at']))
<label for="lead_at" id="lead_at">Lead At: {{ Format::shortDateTime($user['lead_at']) }}</label>
@endif
```

Comment: What is the data inside `$user['lead_at']`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte It's a TIMESTAMP table in our DB. Returns data as 2014-04-23 10:51:07

Comment: Where does that `Format::shortDateTime()` come from? I'm having trouble finding any reference to that in Laravel docs (or anywhere for that matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel comes with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/)

You can do

```
<label for="lead_at" id="lead_at">Lead At: {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user['lead_at'])->format('d/m/Y h:i:s a'); }}
```

The format is up to you. Read about the options here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: That works perfectly @Felippe. I'll investigate the docs more thoroughly next time.